# When to scale Rails apps horizontally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, vps

Many VPS start with a 512MB plan which is just enough for a basic Rails app. RAM is the most obvious limiting factor and one likely to demand an upgrade. This can be solved in two ways:

1. Upgrade to a hosting plan with more RAM
2. Add another server and move some services (like database)

From a price point of view, a 2x ram upgrade in one server cost the same as 2x ram upgrade by spinning up a new server.

The complexity of managing more servers is not an issue in my case. Also I do believe that scaling horizontally should be done the soonest possible to discover edge cases earlier.

Aside from maintenance cost. Is there any benefit or measurement I should be aware of before adding more servers to a Rails deployment?

I am aware that sooner or later I will need more power out of my servers. My focus is on the first initial upgrades: more servers vs more power.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the RAM. It's an order of magnitude simpler and even if you put the DB on a second server, 512MB isn't enough to run a Rails production site receiving any amount of traffic anyway.

Digital Ocean charges $5/mo for 512 and $20/mo for 2GB.  Is it worth $180/yr for the extra hassle?  IMHO, it's not. Linode is similar. I'm sure they all are.

Now, that all said, if you expect you'll grow to really need multiple servers (both database, app, web, etc.) then it certainly doesn't hurt to start thinking about it as there are things you'll need to keep in mind.  The most trivial example being that file based caching doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Actually I never touch my servers directly. I test my Chef cookbooks on a local virtual machine and push the updates. In my case managing 1 or 1000 does not make that much of a difference. Since it is so easy to split servers  and I am very curious to experience a more distributed setup, I was more concerned about spreading out way too early. Although I must admit that maybe 512mb might be a tad too early.

Comment: If you're curious, then by all means do it.  At worst you don't need it. At best you've made the necessary changes that a distributed setup requires and paved the way to quickly/easily add more capacity when you do need it.  I do it. Don't technically need to, but I like the redundancy and the other day when Linode had forced restarts for a Xen security issue, no one noticed as each one went down in turn.